# Formatting OpenBSD partition

Tags: openbsd

I have an (MBR) external hard drive with the following partitions:

250GB `xfs`,   600GB `swap`,   81GB `vfat`

The `swap` partition is actually a placeholder for a single OpenBSD filesystem.

I've tried using `fdisk` to change the partition type to OpenBSD (`A6`) but `disklabel` only recognises the other two. Using `disklabel` without `fdisk` does not let me change the partition type to `4.2BSD`.

I gather from documentation that I should use `fdisk` to create a MBR partition in which to then use `disklabel` to create filesystems.

I would rather ask than lose data. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the question ? What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disklabel` doesn't show the OpenBSD partition because you are using `disklabel` to edit the structure of it. If you execute `p g` in the prompt of `disklabel`, it will show something like this:

```
OpenBSD area: 64-1234567890; size: 0.0G; free: 600.0G
```

You can add the partitions with the command `a`. To add the first partition use `a a`, for the swap `a b`, for the third partition `a d`. The partition `b` is used for the swap and `c` is the hard disk. It's the convention used traditionally by the BSD OS.

`disklabel` will not destroy the data in the Linux/Windows partitions, it only works within the limits of the OpenBSD partition. `fdisk` can destroy everything.

If you want something easy, use `A` in the `disklabel` prompt. It creates a structure with different partitions. With `c letterofpartition`, you can change the partition sizes. `h` shows the different commands.